# SQL Join two querys, same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this table:

[image]

I want to choose the last two entries (the two with the largest id's) no matter what, 
and also the 4 entries that have the most 'power' both queries joined together.

So in this example I would only have 4 results, id 9 & 8, 3 & 4.

I tried:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table 
          ORDER BY power DESC LIMIT 4 
          INNER JOIN SELECT * FROM table 
                     ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 ";
```

I'm getting the "Invalid query" error. What is wrong here?

Comment: You want a union not a join query

Comment: I've tried bensiu answer and i get "Invalid query: Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
( SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY power DESC LIMIT 4 )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2 )
```

Comment: With a UNION I think you would want LIMIT 2 on the first SELECT instead of LIMIT 4.

Comment: Oh god i can't believe i've forgot the UNION ! takes me back to sql injection methods, thanks!

Comment: To solve the problem, I wraped each individual SELECT statement in parenthesis, Thanks.

Comment: Sorry my bad - try to do it too fast - I just did it and you fund it at this same time

Answer (score 3):

`JOIN`is not what you want, but `UNION` will return some Rows twice (when matching both queries). I have no MySQL at hand, but try Subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
OR id IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY power DESC LIMIT 4)
```

Comment: default duplicate rows are eliminated and that's exactly what i needed. thanks.

Comment: MySQL uses `UNION DISTINCT` by default, so it will not produce duplicate rows, my fault ^^

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is an UNION and not an INNER JOIN

Example:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1  
UNION  
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2
```

Union appends the results of two select statements together. I would recommend reading Jeff Atwood's post on SQL joins for a better idea on what the various joins do. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html